# Android Studio not generating native debug symbols

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-console

I am trying to release an update for my Android app that I'm creating with Ionic.

In developer's console, I update my Android Bundle, but it is requiring both the mapping file AND native debug symbols Zip file.

[image]

I managed to get Android Studio to generate the mapping file.

However, **I can't get Android Studio to generate the native debug symbols**.

I'm following [THIS](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633#zippy=%2Cnative-generate-a-debug-symbols-file) guide.

I installed, from the SDK Manager, CMake and NDK (Side by Side)

[image]

I added `android.defaultConfig.ndk.debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'` to the end of build.gradle (:app)

[image]

Then, I sync the build.gradle, build the project and generate the signed bundle, but I just can't get the *native-debug-symbols* folder under ".../app/build/outputs" as the guide said it would be automatically generate. The only folders I get are *apk*, *logs* and *mapping*

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I generate these native debug symbols? Why can't I just simply update my app?

Comment: You got solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On the SDK Tools windows:

- Check the "Show Package Details" option
- Expand NDK, find the selected NDK version, and copy the version name

[image]

2. Open your app build.gradle

- add ndkVersion "Your copied NDK version" under android

[image]

Then native debug symbol zip will be added to your AAB file when you build it.

Answer (score 0):

Although in Play Console it shows as "required features", it turns out that you can ignore uploading this step of uploading Native Debug Symbols. You can look for the "Next" or "Submit to review" button.

Unfortunately, it was not clear enough, so I wasted a whole bunch of time just to know the "required feature" was skippable.